# Pass parameters to controller from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameters

I have a button on my page and on click I have javascript function that 
looks like this:

```
   function PrintPdf() {
    var caseSearch = new Object();
    caseSearch.CustId = $('#CustId').val();
    caseSearch.CustName = $('#CustName').val();
    caseSearch.CustAddress = $('#CustAddress').val();
    caseSearch.CustPhone = $('#CustPhone').val();
    caseSearch.CustMobile = $('#CustMobile').val();
    caseSearch.SubTypeId = $('#CaseTypesDropDown').val();
    caseSearch.CaseStatusId = $('#CaseStatusDropDown').val();
    caseSearch.CreatorId = $('#slcOperId').val();
    caseSearch.TechnicianId = $('#slcTechId').val();
    caseSearch.CallDateFrom = $("#callDatefrom").val();
    caseSearch.CallDateTo = $("#callDateto").val();
    caseSearch.VisitDateFrom = $("#visitDatefrom").val();
    caseSearch.VisitDateTo = $("#visitDateto").val();
    caseSearch.RowsCount = $("#CaseRowsDropDown").val();
var url =  "/Home/PrintPdf?CustId=" + caseSearch.CustId + "&CustName=" + caseSearch.CustName + "&CustAddress=" + caseSearch.CustAddress +
        "&CustPhone=" + caseSearch.CustPhone + "&CustMobile=" + caseSearch.CustMobile + "&SubTypeId=" + caseSearch.SubTypeId + "&CaseStatusId=" + caseSearch.CaseStatusId +
        "&CreatorId=" + caseSearch.CreatorId + "&TechnicianId=" + caseSearch.TechnicianId + "&CallDateFrom=" + caseSearch.CallDateFrom + "&CallDateTo=" + caseSearch.CallDateTo +
        "&VisitDateFrom=" + caseSearch.VisitDateFrom + "&VisitDateTo=" + caseSearch.VisitDateTo;

    window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

All the parameters work perfect except date values.javascript is sending correct values. here is a url :   http://localhost:X/Home/PrintPdf?CustId=&CustName=&CustAddress=&CustPhone=&CustMobile=&SubTypeId=0&CaseStatusId=0&CreatorId=0&TechnicianId=117&CallDateFrom=09/11/2018&CallDateTo=14/11/2018&VisitDateFrom=&VisitDateTo=

But in my PrintPdf method I am getting different date values. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE5SU.png)

Comment: You need to cast the date properly. Please post your server side code

Comment: there aren't any values assigned to cusId, custName, custAddress, custPhone, custMobile ..etc. you better check your jquery library linked correctly. and also post your `input form` code

Comment: In this case I just assigned TechnicianId ,CallDateFrom and CallDateTo. That's not the problem

Comment: How can I cast date?. In this Case  CallDateFrom is 09/11/2018, but in my controller it appears as 11/09/2018 and CallDateTo is 14/11/2018, but it apperas as minValue 01/01/0001. How's that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sending the dates as seconds since Jan 1, 1970 (EPOCH). Something like this:

```
var caseSearch.CallDateFrom =
  Math.round(Date.parse($("#callDatefrom").val()) / 1000);
```

and then convert it back to Date object [or similar] in the receiving end.